# Fail to configure Windows Server 2008 R2 updates

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-machines

I have installed Windows Server 2008 R2 on a VM workstation 9.0 machine. then i have enabled the windows updates which installed around 120 updates . but when i shut down the VM to configure the new updates it raised an error that it can not configure the updates and it revert them back.

So can anyone advice what the problem might be. Baring in mind that i have created an old VM on the same station and i used the same windows server ISO image and the updates were installed without any problems.

thanks in advance for any help.
BR

Answer (score 1):

if you visit windows update history, you should see the error code for the failed updates. Try googling around for the error code and see if you can come up with something.

Also, the updates may fail when many concurrent updates that require restart are installed at once and sometimes the .NET framework updates were to blame.

If you still have problems, maybe something got wrong during the installation and the updater might be corrupt, do a system file check using the following console command:

```
sfc /scannow
```

Also snapshots are a good idea before every major OS modification such as system patches :)

Hope I helped you at least a little.

Comment: the check mentioned that there are no errors, but still the VM can not configure the windows updates